# calling apex.widget.datepicker from embedded JavaScript inside page

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to call apex.widget.datepicker to apply a custom datepicker with the time to a field inside "Execute when Page Loads". In previous versions of Apex this worked fine but we have recently migrated to Apex 4.1.1.00.23

The JS error I get when the page loads is "TypeError: can't convert undefined to object"

On another note I could change the type of field to date, but how can I then customise the jquery date object that has been binded to that particular field?

Comment: I've been breaking my head over this aswell. Works fine on 4.1.0, but on apex.oracle.com it breaks, with this error. I'm stumped honestly. I've been checking the javascript files, and even though there were changes in them from 4.1 to 4.1.1, i suppose the problem must be even deeper... The error is actually thrown in the main 4.1 minified script, which by far resembles nothing like the non-minified version.  I'm still searching.

Comment: @Tom Hey Tom, thanks for the response I feel a bit better knowing that I'm not alone! :) I did find a way around it. Instead of using apex.widget.datepicker you can just use $('#my-field').datepicker({}); You can still pass all the widget parameters and it will parse them. It works for me!

Comment: I agree, but it is still a workaround :( I also reacted on OTN, and i've been spending some more time on it today and only found a bit more weirdness. I don't exactly want to c+p the widget code unless i have to; what it does is nice (like the locale settings). If i ever find an answer i'll be sure to update.

Comment: @Tom I know what you mean, that's great. Thanks.

Comment: I've been spending a lot of headache over this, and i think i'm close to working it out. However, i only have access to to a 4.1.0 release at work. Since apex.oracle.com upgraded to 4.2 i can't check any longer what went wrong in 4.1.1. Not all hope lost however: contact me by mail, it'll be easier to send over some instructions

Comment: @Tom That's great, how do I contact you by email? I can't seem to find the option to do that on here.

Comment: @Tom No worries thanks, got your email, you can delete the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i got access to a 4.1.1 workspace (since apex.oracle.com was updated to 4.2) I promptly tried to reproduce the issues. However, i can't!
I'd swear i had an issue on apex.oracle.com, but i'm not so sure anymore whether i made a mistake.

Actually, 4.1.0 and 4.1.1 respond exactly the same, as i would actually expect them to. 4.2 is different, but only by a little. I don't know why i have wasted so much time up until now, i must have really been missing some obvious logical flaw.

I don't know what changed between 4.0 and 4.1 though, so i'm not sure what you did to initialize a datepicker in 4.0. If all you had to do was to call `apex.widget.datepicker` on an item to get it to work, in 4.1 that changes a little as there is an extra step involved.

Before calling `apex.widget.datepicker`, you have to make sure a locale has been loaded. I spied this from inspecting the ajax calls made by apex when opening the *actions > filter* menu. That code appends a script tag with a source set to datepicker locale files in the `apex_images` directory. The file initializes some variables in the datepicker.
For example, an application with language english = `'en'`, would initialize as `apex.jQuery.datepicker.regional['en']`

This is important, because if this doesn't happen, you get the `undefined` object error, since the widget code attempts to access those locale variables. If the script code has not been appended, they won't be, and `apex.widget.datepicker` will throw an error.

To make sure the datepicker code works, you will need to include the locale javascript file. You can do this by adding it to your page header, in the page itself, the template, or you can do it dynamically: it's up to you to decide the best place.

Here is an example of dynamically adding the locale file:

```
$(document).append('<script type="text/javascript" src="/i/libraries/jquery-ui/1.8.14/ui/i18n/oracle/jquery.ui.datepicker-en.js"></script>');
```

This will get the file in the given directory (same as actions>filter would do), and it looks as this:

```
//******  AMERICAN  ******
apex.jQuery(function($){
apex.jQuery.datepicker.regional['en'] = {
closeText: "Close",
prevText: "Prev",
nextText: "Next",
currentText: "Today",
monthNames: ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December" ],
monthNamesShort: ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec" ],
dayNames: ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday" ],
dayNamesShort: ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat" ],
dayNamesMin: ["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa" ],
weekHeader: "Wk",
dateFormat: "dd-M-y",firstDay: 0,
isRTL: false,
showMonthAfterYear: false,
yearSuffix: ""};
apex.jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults(apex.jQuery.datepicker.regional['en']);
});
```

Now, do notice that that path has some hard-coding issues. There is '/i/', the jquery version, and the locale. Not much can be done about the jquery version.
`/i/` can be replaced by `apex_img_dir`
locale can be caught with the `BROWSER_LANGUAGE` application variable

```
$(document).append('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+apex_img_dir+'libraries/jquery-ui/1.8.14/ui/i18n/oracle/jquery.ui.datepicker-&BROWSER_LANGUAGE..js"></script>');
```

should do the trick (*inspect your ajax call to make sure!*)

Once the script has been included, it should be safe to call apex.widget.datepicker!

Now, i've also been experimenting on **4.2**, and it's mostly the same there. The only thing which has changed **is that you have to include the widget code**!

```
$(document).append('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+apex_img_dir+'libraries/jquery-ui/1.8.22/ui/i18n/oracle/jquery.ui.datepicker-en.js"></script>' +
'<script type="text/javascript" src="'+apex_img_dir+'libraries/apex/minified/widget.datepicker.min.js?v=4.2.0.00.19"></script>');
```

That should cover most of it.